# Emgu.CV.CvEnum.IPL_DEPTH.IPL_DEPTH_32F and Emgu.CV.CvEnum.IplDepth.IplDepth32F

Tags: emgucv

I'm new to emgu, and found people are using Emgu.CV.CvEnum.IPL_DEPTH.IPL_DEPTH_32F in their implementation. In my program, I don't know why I can not use it. However, I found that I could use Emgu.CV.CvEnum.IplDepth.IplDepth32F. I'm guessing they are the same thing, but I'm using a different version of emgu from other people. I'm using emgu.cv.dll version 3.0.0.2157. I tried to find which version uses Emgu.CV.CvEnum.IPL_DEPTH.IPL_DEPTH_32F as other people are using, but didn't get any luck. I probably referred to the wrong place. Can any one tell how to figure out such problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when faced with something like this I go to the [Emgu.CV web site](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) and look in the [API documentation](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Documentation). I checked v2.4.10 and that version uses IPL_DEPTH_32F. If they are using 2.4.10 then you are fine.

I will let you check other versions if necessary.

Doug